# x7 Chat install problems

Tags: php

I am using X7 Chat and trying to install it on my localhost. I got an error  on the install.php Here's what I have:

[image: Chat Error]

I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help please?
And here's the code on the install.php:

```
<?php if(empty($fail)): ?>
    <form id="dbform">
        <?php if(!$config): ?>
            <h2>Database Connection Details</h2>
            <b><label for="host">Database Host</label></b>
            <input type="text" name="host" value="localhost" />
            <hr />
            <b><label for="user">Database Username</label></b>
            <input type="text" name="user" value="" />
            <hr />
            <b><label for="pass">Database Password</label></b>
            <input type="password" name="pass" value="" />
            <hr />
            <b><label for="dbname">Database Name</label></b>
            <input type="text" name="dbname" value="" />
            <hr />
            <b><label for="prefix">Table Prefix</label></b>
            <input type="text" name="prefix" value="x7chat_" />
            <hr />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <h2>Admin Account Details</h2>
        <b><label for="admin_username">Admin Username</label></b>
        <input type="text" name="admin_username" value="" />
        <hr />
        <b><label for="admin_username">Admin Password</label></b>
        <input type="password" name="admin_password" value="" />
        <hr />
        <b><label for="retype_admin_password">Retype Admin Password</label></b>
        <input type="password" name="retype_admin_password" value="" />
        <hr />
        <b><label for="admin_email">Admin E-Mail</label></b>
        <input type="text" name="admin_email" value="" />
        <hr />
        <h2>Chatroom Details</h2>
        <b><label for="title">Chatroom Name</label></b>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="" />
        <hr />
        <input id="continue" type="submit" value="Continue" />
    </form>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>One or more critical checks failed.  Please correct them before installing X7 Chat.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `$config` is not defined. Use `!empty` or `isset` to not have notice thrown....or find where you think you are defining it and see why it actually isn't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)